# Android: Erratic behavior when Drawing rectangle using 2 multi touch points

Tags: android, canvas, multi-touch

After doing some tutorials on touch events and drawing on a canvas I tried to combine what I learned and make an application that creates a rectangle using 2 touch points. I am able to drag and create a rectangle using a single touch point but as soon as I use a second finger the rectangle starts behaving weirdly, either not drawing the rectangle at all or disappearing after dragging it a bit. Furthermore, if for example I draw a rectangle by having one touch point being on the lower left corner and the other one on the upper right corner of the screen the rectangle disappears if I drag my fingers to the point where they cross each other.

[gif of the application running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXZ9N.gif)

```
private float xDown = 0,yDown = 0, xUp = 0, yUp = 0;
boolean touched = false;


@Override
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)  {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    if(touched) {
        canvas.drawRect(xDown, yDown, xUp, yUp, mPaint);

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    int fingers = event.getPointerCount();
    switch (event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (fingers == 1) {
                xDown = event.getX(0);
                yDown = event.getY(0);

                xUp = 0;
                yUp = 0;
            }
            if (fingers == 2) {
                xUp = event.getX(1);
                yUp = event.getY(1);
                xDown = event.getX(0);
                yDown = event.getY(0);
                touched = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (fingers == 1) {
                xUp = event.getX();
                yUp = event.getY();
                touched = true;
            }
            if (fingers == 2) {
                xUp = event.getX(1);
                yUp = event.getY(1);
                xDown = event.getX(0);
                yDown = event.getY(0);
                touched = true;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (fingers == 1) {
                xUp = event.getX();
                yUp = event.getY();
                touched = true;
            }

            if (fingers == 2) {
                xUp = event.getX(1);
                yUp = event.getY(1);
                xDown = event.getX(0);
                yDown = event.getY(0);
                touched = true;
            }

            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN will only happen with the **FIRST** touch event to the screen.

"ACTION_DOWN

Constant for getActionMasked(): A pressed gesture has started..."  (From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_DOWN)

For your **SECOND** *or more* fingers, you need to check for **ACTION_POINTER_DOWN**

"ACTION_POINTER_DOWN

Constant for getActionMasked(): A non-primary pointer has gone down..." (From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)

Because you are using only two fingers, you won't need to worry about the ActionIndex ( getActionIndex() ).  The first finger touching the screen is always an **ACTION_DOWN** and every touch down after is an **ACTION_POINTER_DOWN**.

On the ACTION_UP it is the reverse.  Every touch up (except the last touch) is ACTION_POINTER_UP and the last touch up is an ACTION_UP.

NOTE: The first touch (ACTION_DOWN) always has and index of 0.
The index stays assigned to the touch until the touch is removed from the screen. Because you are hard-coding the indexes, any accidental touches to the screen will cause some unexpected results.  For a test program, this is fine but you will need to handle the indexes eventually.

Example:

> Finger 1 (ACTION_DOWN) touches the screen and gets an index of 0.
>   Finger 2 (ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) touches the screen and gets an index of 1.
>   Finger 3 (ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) touches the screen and gets an index of 2
>
> Finger 2 (index 1) is lifted off the screen (ACTION_POINTER_UP)
>
> Finger 1 (index 0) and finger 3 (index 2) are still in the MotionEvent and their indexes remain assigned to them.

The simplest change for you to make is Change:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
   if (fingers == 1) {
...
```

to:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
   if (fingers == 1) {
...
```

and also Change:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   if (fingers == 1) {
...
```

to:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
   if (fingers == 1) {
...
```

because you are already handling the finger count & indexes.

This change will make you code "more correct" because it will capture the second DOWN and the first UP but it will not fix your issue.  ACTION_MOVE is already catching both touch points when they move and you are already handling the two indexes and assigning the X's & Y's.  So the issue has to be elsewhere in you program.